# How to read multiple excel files using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, tkinter

I want the user to select two files from his computer and after "Calculate" button is pressed, the program will display the Cross-Talk function result of the data read from these Excel Files. I'm currently unable to read two Excel files simultaneously into the program. Here's my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import os.path as op

fileListA = ""
fileListB = ""
def SetFilePath1():
    #Getting the file from PC
    filepath = fd.askopenfilename(filetypes =(('Excel Files', '.xls'), ('Excel Files','*.xlsx')),parent=root)
    if isinstance(filepath, str):
        fileListA = filepath.split(" ")
    elif isinstance(filepath, tuple):
        fileListA = list(filepath)
    elif isinstance(filepath, list):
        fileListA = filepath
def SetFilePath2():
    #Getting the file from PC
    filepath = fd.askopenfilename(filetypes =(('Excel Files', '.xls'), ('Excel Files','*.xlsx')),parent=root)
    if isinstance(filepath, str):
        fileListB = filepath.split(" ")
    elif isinstance(filepath, tuple):
        fileListB = list(filepath)
    elif isinstance(filepath, list):
        fileListB = filepath
def GetFilePath1():
    #Getting the file from PC
    return fileListA
def GetFilePath2():
    #Getting the file from PC
    return fileListB
def Calculate():
    file1 = GetFilePath1()
    file2 = GetFilePath2()
    print("Inside Calculate")
    print(file1)

    print("Inside If Loop")

    if file1 == "":
        print("File 1 Not Found")
    elif file2 == "":
        print("File 2 Not Found")
    else:
        print("Inside If Loop")
        #Creating DataFrames as df1 & df2 with Header=None because currently no header in the excel files
        df1 = pd.read_excel(open(file1,'rb'), header=None)
        #Setting the header for the dataframes as title. This will not change anything in the original files
        df1.rename(columns={0 : 'title',},inplace=True)

        df2 = pd.read_excel(open(file2,'rb'), header=None)
        #Setting the header for the dataframes as title. This will not change anything in the original files
        df2.rename(columns={0 : 'title',},inplace=True)

        #Doing the mathematics line 24 to line 39
        df1['Value'] = (df1.title * 32.7) ** 2
        df2['Value'] = (df2.title * 32.7) ** 2

        df1['Emen'] = df1.Value * df2.Value

        #output is just one value of these sum and sqrt functions
        df1['TotalD'] = df1['Emen'].sum()
        df1['TotalC'] = df1['Value'].sum()
        df2['TotalC'] = df2['Value'].sum()

        df1['SqrtC'] = df1.TotalC ** 0.5
        df2['SqrtC'] = df2.TotalC ** 0.5

        df1['MulG'] = df1.SqrtC * df2.SqrtC
        df1['DivH'] = df1.TotalD / df1.MulG
        df1['SqH'] = df1.DivH * df1.DivH

        print("Here is the Cross-Talk: ")
        print(df1.SqH[0])


root = Tk()
root.title("Cross-Talk Calculator")     
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

ttk.Label(mainframe).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="File 1", command=SetFilePath1).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E)

ttk.Label(mainframe).grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="File 2", command=SetFilePath2).grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="The Cross Talk is: ").grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", command=lambda: Calculate()).grid(column=3, row=4, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

root.bind('<Return>')

root.mainloop()
```

The mathematical part of the code works fine. I have used print() to know where is my code currently. I've searched alot on the internet but couldn't find any solution to my problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please describe what "I'm currently unable to read two Excel files simultaneously into the program. Here's my code" means exactly. Error messages? Unexpected behaviour?

Comment: you create local variables `fileListA` and `fileListB` in function. In functions you have to use `global fileListA` and/or `global fileListB` to inform function that you what to use (external) global variable.

Comment: BTW: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - we rather use `UpperCaseNames` for classes (like `Label`, `Button`), and `lower_cas_names` for functions/variables/instances (like `set_file_path2`) to make code more readable. Even SO knows this suggestion and use light blue color for classes.

Comment: there is no sense to use `GetFilePath1()` if you can get `fileListA` directly - `file1 = fileListA`. Python is not Java which likes getter/setter methods (`GetSomethig()` , `SetSomething()`)

Comment: I'm new to python and it'd take me a lot of time to learn the ethics of coding in Python. btw could you please give me the line number to place global variable into my code @furas

Comment: @Omni Unexpected behaviour

Comment: While we are speaking of style guidelines, it improves readability to add one or two newlines in between functions, like in furas's answer.

Comment: global fileListA
global fileListB

fileListA = ""
fileListB = ""

at the start of the code after importing packages, but I'm still getting error
"FileListA is not defined"

Comment: I don't see `'FileListA'` with upper `F` in your code in question - probably in new code you put  `'FileListA'` with upper `F`. Full error message (Traceback) should show you in which line you have mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fileListA` and `fileListB` are global variables. In functions `SetFilePath1` and `SetFilePath2` you create local variables `fileListA` and `fileListB`. You have to use `global` in functions to inform them that you want to assign to global variables.

BTW: you don't have to use `global` if you only get value from global variable - like in `Calculate`.

```
fileListA = ""  # it is global variable (automatically)
fileListB = ""  # it is global variable (automatically)

def SetFilePath1():
    global fileListA # inform function to assign value (when you use `=`)   
                     # to external variable instead of creating local variable

    #Getting the file from PC
    filepath = fd.askopenfilename(filetypes =(('Excel Files', '.xls'), ('Excel Files','*.xlsx')),parent=root)
    if isinstance(filepath, str):
        fileListA = filepath.split(" ")
    elif isinstance(filepath, tuple):
        fileListA = list(filepath)
    elif isinstance(filepath, list):
        fileListA = filepath

def SetFilePath2():
    global fileListB # inform function to assign value (when you use `=`)   
                     # to external variable instead of creating local 

    #Getting the file from PC
    filepath = fd.askopenfilename(filetypes =(('Excel Files', '.xls'), ('Excel Files','*.xlsx')),parent=root)
    if isinstance(filepath, str):
        fileListB = filepath.split(" ")
    elif isinstance(filepath, tuple):
        fileListB = list(filepath)
    elif isinstance(filepath, list):
        fileListB = filepath

def Calculate():
    file1 = fileListA
    file2 = fileListB
    print("Inside Calculate")
    print(file1)
    # ... rest ...
```

Comment: The code gives an error "NameError: name 'FileListA' is not defined " @furas

Comment: in example I don't use `'FileListA'` with upper `F`  - probaly you have in your code  `'FileListA'` with upper `F`. Full error message (Traceback) should show you in which line you have mistake.